# Lightning init not getting second time

Tags: apex, lightning

I have written a lightning component to update a field value & return back the detail page. This lightning component is getting invoked through a formula link on a detail page where i am passing some arguments through the URL. The code works perfectly well for the first time but subsequently it doesn't work. I need to refresh the detail page & again click on the link to make it work.

````
Component:
ReadParameter.cmp
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,lightning:isUrlAddressable" controller="Apts_OSW_quoteChangeController">
    <aura:attribute name="page_Reference" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="quoteId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="statusc" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="idNum" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    Lightning Component received Account Name - {!v.quoteId} 
    Lightning Component status -{!v.statusc}
    Lightning Component number -{!v.idNum}
</aura:component>


```
Component Controller:
ReadParameterController.cmp
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Calling helper');
        helper.updateStatus(component);
        console.log('Called helper');
    }
})

```
Helper:
({
    updateStatus : function(component) {
        var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");

        component.set("v.quoteId", pageReference.state.c__quoteId);
        component.set("v.statusc", pageReference.state.c__status);
        component.set("v.idNum", pageReference.state.c__identityNumber);
        var action = component.get("c.quoteChange");

        action.setParams({  proposalId :  component.get("v.quoteId"),status:component.get("v.statusc"), identityNumber:component.get("v.idNum")});

         //$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
         //
         action.setCallback(this,function(response) {    

            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state'+state);
            if (state === "SUCCESS") { 

                var urlRedirect= $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");

                urlRedirect.setParams({
                    "url": "/" + component.get("v.quoteId")
                });
                urlRedirect.fire();
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('ERROR');
                // generic error handler
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    console.log("Errors", errors);

                        throw new Error("Error" + errors[0].message);

                } else {
                    throw new Error("Unknown Error");
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    } ,

})
````

Answer (score 0):

This controller will be invoked only once since it is invoked only on init, that is when page loads.

On subsequent changes, it should be handled separately either through change event. Like

`<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.attributeName}" action="{!c.updateStatus}"/>`

Comment: The subsequent I referred is completely different from what you have explained over here. The scenario I was trying to explain is that I click on a detail page link & my component is invoked which updates the record & returns back to detail page. But immediately if I click on the same detail page link, my init method doesn't get executed. I would have to explicitly refresh my page to return to detail page.